# Google Data Studio - Cloud SQL For MySQL Connector Error

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, looker-studio

I have created a MySQL 8.0 instance on GCP and trying to connect to it through
Cloud SQL for MySQL connector available with Google data Studio .
I have followed all the instructions provided in https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020436?hl=en&ref_topic=6370347
I could connect to the MySQL through MySQL Workbench and as well as through my sql command using the SSL (server cert ,client cert and client key) but not able to connect through "Cloud SQL for MySQL connector" .
I am not able establish connection through even "My SQL connector".

I have opened Public IP and even whitelisted all the google data studio IPs which is not needed for "Cloud SQL for MySQL connector"

I tried using the root user as well as the new user "testuser" with access from '%'

Could you please let me know what could be wrong? are there any IAM restrictions should I look into?

**UPDATE** - If the gcp cloud MySQL version is 5.7 , the "Cloud SQL for MySQL" connector successfully establishes the connection. It looks like the issue is while connecting to Cloud MySQL8.0

[image: connetion error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your configuration. It's that Datastudio doesn't support connecting to  MySQL version 8 yet. Here's a [support thread](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/4115506?msgid=34547134) that contains a workaround, it uses ProxySQL.

Another alternative is that you create another Cloud SQL for MySQL instance and use version 5.7.

Also, here's a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/167924845) from Google where you can receive an update. Simply leave a comment and indicate that you're affected by the issue.

> Take note that there's no ETA when the feature will roll out.

Comment: Thank you!! I spent a lot of time researching this. Initially I was trying MySQL8 on AWS RDS and couldn't connect through Data Studio. Then thought of implementing MySQL* on GCP expecting Data Studio to work without any issues connecting to Google cloud. Turns out its the version issue, found it the hard way!!